# How to not include source files in my conan package?

Tags: conan

We are trying to manage our own C++ static libraries using JFrog Artifactory CE. In the near future, these libraries could be accessed by third parties so we don't want to put any .cpp files in the package, we just want to put .h files and compiled libraries in our conan packages hosted on Artifcatory.

I read through the conan official guide https://docs.conan.io/en/1.3/creating_packages.html
https://docs.conan.io/en/1.3/creating_packages/package_repo.html

but I cannot find any description of how to exclude source files from the recipe.
If I don't specify **exports_sources** or **exports** in my conanfile.py I cannot build static libraries but if I specify those parameters, conan puts source files under export/conan_sources.tgz automatically when I execute conan create.

How can I create a conan package without including source files in the recipe?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different ways to do this, instead of using the `exports_...` functionality:

- Use the `source()` method, to retrieve whatever tarball, git-clone, or what is necessary to fetch the sources. This might require some authentication, which can be provided through env-vars. It is typical to use the `conandata.yml` to put the data there, and let the `source()` method to read the `self.conan_data`. Check [this docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/external_repo.html#recipe-and-sources-in-a-different-repo). The recipes in the [conan-center-index repo](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index), that serves to build ConanCenter, uses this approach.
- Use the `scm` component if the recipe lives in the same repo as the source code, to capture the URL and commit of the sources, but without capturing the sources. If the `scm` code is behind auth, only authorized devs will be able to see the sources or build from sources. Check this [section of the docs about SCM](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/package_repo.html#capturing-the-remote-and-commit-scm)

In both cases, if the access to the source is restricted, non-privileged users that try to build packages from sources with `--build` will fail.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try both ways and compare them.